# .htm file in JavaScript will not display the correct color

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>
<body bgcolor=”WHITE”> 

<p>Paragraph 1</p>

<script type=”text/javascript”>
document.bgColor = “RED”; </script>

</body> 
</html>
```

when I save as .htm file and open it in safari or google chrome, it displays a black screen. can be found on http://www.yaldex.com/javascript_tutorial_3/LiB0012.html

Comment: not clear what you are asking.  And what does jquery have to do with this.

Comment: it was just a suggested tag, I just selected all of the suggested tags.

Comment: Please be specific to your question

Comment: I don't know why you are using some sort of script to change the background color.  Just use css or even a simple style attribute.

Comment: `bgcolor` is deprecated also

Comment: and CAP LETTERS FOR COLORS JUST suxors!

Comment: `<html>
<body style="background-color:green;"> 
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
</body> 
</html>`

Comment: Those quotes are wrong... Fancy quotes = bad, pick a better editor.

Comment: That is a truly ancient tutorial, it talks about **Netscape Navigator**! - ignore it *completely* and find a more recent one.

Comment: It was a direct copy/paste from Beginning JavaScript by Paul Wilton page 41

Comment: Could you recommend a better book to learn from?

Comment: [Best resources to learn JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body class="body"> 

  <p>Paragraph 1</p>

  <script type=text/javascript>

    $(".body").css("background-color","red");

  </script>

  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is all jacked up... here is a working version:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init() { 
                document.body.style.background = 'red'; 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white" onload="init();"> 
         <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the quotation marks around colors and "text/javascript" . This usually happens when you copy and paste from somewhere directly into your text editor. Replace the quotes by typing in your own quotes and the black screen will go away.
Always use Inspect Element in the browser to see what is wrong.